# About extracting req.body values

Tags: node.js

received as body from the client
I want to get a value as a column and store it in mongo DB using mongoose

```html
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Jayden">
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="Lee">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
<script>
    const form = document.getElementById('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const payload = new FormData(form);

      fetch('http://localhost:4000/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: payload,
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
    });
  </script>
```

[image]

```js
app.post("/add",(req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

[image]

but such like
[req.body.name
req.body.surname]
If I import it into a column like this, it comes out as undefiend.

```js
app.post("/add",(req, res)=>{
  console.log(req.body.name)
}) //undefined
```

so I tried :

```js
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({dest : 'uploads/'})
...

app.use('/add', upload.fields([{name : 'name'},{name:'surname'}]), (req, res, next) => {
    const {name,surname} = req.body;
    res.send(req.body);
    console.log(req.body)
  });
```

[image]

But I wanted to get the filename as well, so I tried something like this:

```js
app.use('/add', upload.fields([{name : 'name'},{name:'surname'}]), (req, res, file, next) => {
    const {name,surname} = req.body;
  const {filename} = file.originalname;
    res.send(req.body);
    console.log(req.body)
  });
  app.use('/add', upload.fields([{name : 'name'},{name:'surname'},{name:'file'}]), (req, res, file, next) => {
    const {name,surname} = req.body;
    const {filename} = req.file;
      res.send(req.body);
      console.log(req.body)
  });
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need a body parser on the node.js side. Assuming you use express https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: You need to use a middleware that can handle `multipart/form-data` (like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)) and also set the `content-type` header to that MIME type.

Comment: @Marc you can't use `body-parser` for file uploads.

Comment: My bad, i over read the file input.

Comment: Thanks robertklep for pointing out. I have overlooked the file upload.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try using multer.

Comment: The value in the text field was fetched successfully.
I want to get the filename, how do I do this?